# How can evaluate field in range?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I trying to create a default template for many similar applications, I need share same PVC with two or more pod and need modify the chart for create ot not PVC, if already exists.

This is my portion of values.yml about volumes:

```
persistence:
  enabled: true

volumeMounts:
  - name: vol1
    mountPath: /opt/vol1
  - name: vol2
    mountPath: /opt/vol2

volumes:
  - name: vol1
    create: true
    claimName: claim-vol1
    storageClassName: gp2
    accessModes: ReadWriteOnce
    storage: 1Gi
  - name: vol2
    create: false
    claimName: claim-vol2
    storageClassName: gp2
    accessModes: ReadWriteOnce
    storage: 1Gi
```

And this is my pvclaim.yml:

```
{{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
{{- if .Values.volumes.create }}
{{- range .Values.volumes }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: {{ .claimName }}
spec:
  storageClassName: {{ .storageClassName }}
  accessModes:
    - {{ .accessModes }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .storage }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

I thought I'd add the field `create` into range of `volumes` to manage creations of PVC (assuming in this example that PVC `vol2` already exists from other helm chart).

If it were possible I would like helm to read the `create` field inside the range, this way I get an error:
`evaluate field create in type interface {}`

If you have any other ideas they are welcome, thanks!

Comment: `volumes` is an array, it does not have a `create` field. _Elements_ of `volumes` have that field. So `.Values.volumes.create` does not make any sense. Inside the `range` you may check the `create` field of the element using `.create`, e.g. `{{if .create}}do something here{{end}}`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! If you response I accept the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`volumes` is an array, it does not have a `create` field.

*Elements* of volumes have that field. So `.Values.volumes.create` does not make any sense. Inside the `range` you may check the `create` field of the element using `.create`, e.g.

```
{{- range .Values.volumes }}
    {{if .create}}do something here{{end}}
{{- end}}
```